# Cannot compile C++ deque.erase() call

Tags: c++, constants, deque

I cannot compile that simple code. Why?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::deque<std::pair<const int, int>> dq;

    // problem with that line
    dq.erase(dq.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using GCC version 7.4.0 on WSL Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

If I define `dq` as `std::deque<std::pair<int, int>> dq;`, all compile nice.

Comment: A [deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) requires the type be copy assignable and copy constructible (pre-C++11); or (C++11 and later) complete type and erasable and other requirements.  A `pair<const int, int>` does not meet the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::deque<T>::erase(const_iterator)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) requires that `T` is move assignable. This is because if you erased something that wasn't at the start or end of the deque, it would have to move everything over (Which you can't do with a pair containing a `const`).

You can use [`std::deque<T>::pop_front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/pop_front) instead, which will work since it only has to destruct an element.